# Magento showing server's IP under remote_ip

Tags: magento-1.9

My magento install showing the server's IP in `sales_flat_order/remote_ip`. I want to show the client's IP.

I already tried [this](https://go.eway.io/s/article/Magento-is-using-the-wrong-customer-IP-address) but not worked.

What to do?

Comment: Can you check that $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] hasn't been added with a value in index.php? I've seen this before when a value has been set for debugging an issue and had been left in which affected the remote ip value.

Comment: No there isn't any variables like that

Comment: are you behind cloudflare or the sort? if so, you'll need to configure nginx / apache appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Please try in your **index.php** file

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORIG_REAL_IP'];
```